# Rails polymorph relation with a controller for the associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to complete my app but I'm blocked in front of a relation.

I have 3 models: Video, Gallery and Content.

Every model is sharable and i have a content_share model. So, for example, I have

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Sharable
end

module Sharable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    has_one :content_share, as: :sharable
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :content_share, reject_if: :all_blank
  end
end

class ContentShare < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sharable, polymorphic: true
  mount_uploader :image, ShareUploader
end
```

I must create a form to create the "content_share".

In my video controller I add:

```
  def activate
    render 'admin/shared/content_share', locals: { shared: video }
  end
```

because I want to reuse the form page also for gallery and video.

Now the problem: with my form

```
= simple_form_for [:admin, shared] do |form|
  = form.fields_for :content_share, shared.build_content_share do |share_form|
```

when I submit my form the action is routed to my video controller. How can I use the content_share controller I created for my model so I avoid the triplication?

Comment: What are you trying to save with the form ?

Comment: some data in my content_share model. Strings and boolean.

Comment: Did you define a route with a POST request in your route.rb file that point to the controller your want ? so that you can use this route in your form with a helper like <%= simple_form_for @content_share, :url => save_content_share_path, :method => :post ... # etc

Comment: @Antoine yes I defined it. The problem is that in my params I lose every reference to my associated model (i lose the relation). I need to keep also sharable_id and sharable_type

Comment: did you define in your ContentShare model did you put `belongs_to :sharable, polymorphic: true` ? Can you edit your question by adding the params ?